# Is factory-based object construction and property assignment possible with LINQ query syntax?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a LINQ query that resembles the following (filters etc. removed for brevity)

```
var orderLines = 
    from line in lines
    select new OrderLine {
        Prop1 = line[0],
        Prop2 = line[1],
        // ... possibly 1-3 more properties are initialized
    };
```

Pretty easy, helpful object initializer syntax makes it all clear. Unfortunately I needed to change the construction of the OrderLine class (to include reference to the order to which it belongs), so I made the default constructor private and exposed factory method. I couldn't figure out how to adapt my queries using LINQ query syntax, so I switched to method syntax:

```
var orderLines = 
    lines.Select(line => {
        var orderLine = Order.CreateOrderLine();
        orderLine.Prop1 = line[0];
        orderLine.Prop2 = line[1];
        return orderLine;
    });
```

Is it possible to use query syntax in this scenario? If so, then how? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Afaik there is no way. Why don't you provide parameters in `CreateOrderLine`?

Comment: Only parameterless constructors and initializers are supported in LINQ to Entities

Answer (score 0):

You can change the signature of `Order.CreateOrderLine` method to the following :

```
//change object for type of Props
public static Order CreateOrderLine(object prop1, object prop2)
{
     //make assignments here
}
```

Answer (score -1):

How about the following:

```
var orderLines = from line in lines
let orderLine = Order.CreateOrderLine()
select new {
    Prop1 = line[0],
    Prop2 = line[1],
};
```

Comment: Thanks Borys. That unfortunately would create anonymous object instead of object of class OrderLine.

Comment: Ok, sorry I overlooked that

Comment: Them I would suggest to go with separate method to keep you code clean, like follows: var orderLines = from line in lines select PrepareOrderLine(line). And PrepareOrderLine will instantiate the object from factory, assign the properties and return the instance